# I read csv into array in java, trying to set the contents of the array into a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, csv, user-interface, combobox

I have read the csv file into an array in java. I am doing this to get the `regPlate` column, in hope of returning all the `regPlates`.
I'm trying to make `allRegPlates` equal to `regPlates[0]` because when I print `regPlates[0]` in the CLI, it shows all of the registration plates column.

Here is my CSV.
[CSV Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8g2f.png)

Here is my code:

Cars.java

```java
package prototype;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Cars {
    
    public String regPlate;
    public double price;
    public String make;
    public String model;
    public String fType;
    public String colour;
    public int mileage;
    public int prevOwners;
    public double mpg;
    public double noughttosixty;
    public int bhp;
    public int maxSpeed;
    public String feature1;
    public String feature2;
    public String feature3;
    public String feature4;
    public boolean sold;
    public double boughtFor;
    public double profit;
    
    public String[] regPlates;
    public String allRegPlates;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public List<String[]> line = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String lines = "";
    
    public String thisLine;

    public List<String> getAllRegPlates() 
    {

        String currentLine = "";
        List<String> allRegPlates = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] tempRegPlates;

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Cars.csv"))) {

            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                tempRegPlates = currentLine.split(",");
                System.out.println(tempRegPlates[0]);
                // Add all found plates to your collection
                allRegPlates.add(tempRegPlates[0]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return allRegPlates;
    }
```

GUI.java

```
Cars cars = new Cars();
        
        List<String> plates = cars.getAllRegPlates(); // get all the plates as list
        String[] platesAsArray = (String[]) plates.toArray();
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 200, 1000, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 124, 123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 275, 189, 7, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);
        
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(platesAsArray);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_comboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);
```

[This is what my GUI shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6QDO.png)

I also get this error:

```java
regPlate
la1 abc
la6 5gb
rifol1
SX72 44
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at prototype.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:98)
    at prototype.GUI$1.run(GUI.java:43)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) In your `getAllRegPlates()` you don't actually summarize all your input into a collection or array. Also, you are returning `colour`, which is not even defined there. You should fix your input first and return a `String[]` of all parsed strings. 2) The exception you are getting tells you exactly what is going on. Please see [How to use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more information on `JComboBox`. Hint, in your case it should be nothing more than `new JComboBox(String[] contents)`.

Comment: @maloomeister Hey, I'm still confused. What do you I actually have to do?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, the first thing would be to fix your input. In your getAllRegPlates() you don't actually summarize all your input into a collection or array. Also, you are returning colour, which is not even defined there.

So here is a modified version of your `getAllRegPlates()` which would return a `List` of Strings containing all the plates found in the CSV file

```
public List<String> getAllRegPlates() {

    String currentLine = "";
    List<String> allRegPlates = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] tempRegPlates;

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Cars.csv"))) {

        while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tempRegPlates = currentLine.split(",");
            System.out.println(tempRegPlates[0]);
            // Add all found plates to your collection
            allRegPlates.add(tempRegPlates[0]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // finally, return the list of regplates
    return allRegPlates;
}
```

As the input should now work, the next step would be to correct the creation of the `JComboBox`. This would look something like this:

```
Cars cars = new Cars();
List<String> plates = cars.getAllRegPlates(); // get all the plates as list
String[] platesAsArray = (String[]) plates.toArray(); // convert to String array
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(platesAsArray); // create the combobox
// finally, do layout stuff and add to your frame / panel
```

Comment: Hi, I did this and get java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
 at prototype.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:111)
 at prototype.GUI$1.run(GUI.java:42)

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your updated code, where the error occurs?

Comment: Sure, just wait a min.
Shall I add my whole code?

Comment: Just add the updated sections of code from your original question.